# Cannot login anymore to XFCE

Tags: 18.04, login, xorg, xfce, login-screen

I cannot login anymore to my XFCE desktop environment, since today.
From the login screen (GDM3, LightDM and SDDM behave the same), I login to my account choosing XFCE, the screen turns black, and it goes back to the login screen.

If I choose Ubuntu (or other choices), it works and I am logged on Ubuntu default desktop manager.

If I choose OpenBox, and I run xfce4-session in terminal, then XFCE runs (but without some features).

I don't see anything I could have done that would cause this, if you have any way to get more debug information it can help me.

- Cannot login to XFCE with a fresh new user
- Can start `xfwm4 --replace`
- Removing `.Xauthority` or `.ICEauthority` does nothing
- Reinstalling `xorg`, `xfce4` does nothing
- LightDM and GDM behave the same
- Xubuntu (instead of XFCE) doesn't work too
- moved `.local` and `.config` (be careful if restore your `.config` backup during an XFCE session and then stop XFCE (or logout), it will overwrite the backup with configuration of the current session (probably clean configuration) instead, to avoid this copy it to restore it instead of moving it) doesn't work too

In logs I found a segfault on `xfdesktop`, but I can run `xfdesktop` from OpenBox

I modified the file `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/50x11-common_determine-startup` redirecting the exec output (and error output) to a file, and I got this:

```
/usr/bin/startxfce4: X server already running on display :0

(xfwm4:4072): dbind-WARNING **: 16:14:12.669: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LqCztRHnpU: Connexion refusée

(xfsettingsd:4073): dbind-WARNING **: 16:14:12.673: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LqCztRHnpU: Connexion refusée
Failed to connect to session manager: Impossible de se connecter au gestionnaire de session : SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined

(xfwm4:4072): xfwm4-WARNING **: 16:14:12.954: Failed to connect to session manager: Impossible de se connecter au gestionnaire de session : SESSION_MANAGER environment variable not defined
/usr/bin/env: «node»: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type

(xfdesktop:4077): dbind-WARNING **: 16:14:12.985: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LqCztRHnpU: Connexion refusée

(orage:4078): dbind-WARNING **: 16:14:12.985: Couldn't connect to accessibility bus: Failed to connect to socket /tmp/dbus-LqCztRHnpU: Connexion refusée
xfwm4: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
xfsettingsd: Fatal IO error 11 (Ressource temporairement non disponible) on X server :0.
orage: Fatal IO error 2 (Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type) on X server :0.
```

It might be related: Firefox and Thunderbird don't start from the icons created automatically (favorite) on Gnome, they just hang with the loading spinner and exit.

The apt log of the day before it stopped working:

```
Upgrade: liblua5.3-0:amd64 (5.3.3-1, 5.3.3-1ubuntu0.18.04.1)
Upgrade: libnss-myhostname:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19)
Upgrade: systemd-sysv:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19)
Upgrade: libwbclient0:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.6, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9), samba-libs:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.6, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9), libsmbclient:amd64 (2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.6, 2:4.7.6+dfsg~ubuntu-0ubuntu2.9)
Upgrade: udev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libudev1:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libudev1:i386 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libudev-dev:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19)
Upgrade: libsystemd0:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libsystemd0:i386 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libpam-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19), libnss-systemd:amd64 (237-3ubuntu10.15, 237-3ubuntu10.19)
Remove: nodejs:amd64 (8.10.0~dfsg-2ubuntu0.4)
```

Also this part of my syslog might be useful:

```
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc dbus-daemon[14771]: [session uid=1000 pid=14771] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.26' (uid=1000 pid=17944 comm="xfdesktop " label="unconfined")
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc systemd[2288]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc dbus-daemon[14771]: [session uid=1000 pid=14771] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc systemd[2288]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc at-spi-bus-launcher[17948]: dbus-daemon[17953]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=1000 pid=17944 comm="xfdesktop " label="unconfined")
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc at-spi2-registr[17956]: Could not open X display
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc at-spi-bus-launcher[17948]: dbus-daemon[17953]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc at-spi-bus-launcher[17948]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc at-spi2-registr[17956]: AT-SPI: Cannot open default display
Apr 15 09:56:39 alagane-pc kernel: [ 4036.040026] xfdesktop[17944]: segfault at e4 ip 00007f935e849680 sp 00007ffec057e208 error 4 in libX11.so.6.3.0[7f935e81d000+133000]
```

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your PC? I had a similar issue when logging out from a Gnome session and trying to login an XFCE session.

Comment: Several times, and I never login to other desktop than XFCE usually.

Comment: Can be related to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1132944/ubuntu-18-login-loop-startx-works

Comment: could you try some logging? see what you get when you hit `esc` or `tab` on boot. also get more system specs using a busybox.

Comment: I don't know if there can be useful informations on boot, since I can still start Gnome but not XFCE.
I cannot hit `esc` or `tab` after login, it loops back to login but nothing is written on screen.
I have no idea what to do with busybox

Comment: Maybe there's something in the ~/.config/xfce4 folder that's causing the problem. Try renaming it and if it boots, albeit as if it where the first time you used xfce, you know the problem lies in the config folder

Comment: New users also have the problem, and moving the entire `.config` and `.local` changes nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I did 2 things that might have resolved the problem:

- Reinstalling `nodejs` (I don't really know why) that was removed the day before I got this bug
- Removing `.dbus` folder in my home directory, it seems it was owned by root

And the things that can help:

- Uninstall every DM (LightDM, GDM3, SDDM), reboot, login in tty, edit `.xinitrc` file and put `exec startxfce4` in it, then just run `startx`, and you might have some more information about why it doesn't work. Xorg logs are not always in the same location, so you have to look at the output of startx to know where it is.

Answer (score 1):

(Adding this because it might help someone in the future.)

In my case the problem was, that the owner of `/home/user/` was root:

```
user@host:~$ ls -l /home/
total 4
drwxr-x--- 10 root root 4096 Jul 19 16:31 user
```

So I fixed it by changing the user and group:

```
sudo chown -hR user:user /home/user/
```

You might want to change the command according to you username.