# Ubuntu 18 login loop + startx works

Tags: 18.04, login, lightdm, login-screen, gdm

So recently I got stuck in a login loop on Ubuntu 18. I tried some solutions posted here but none of them works for me so far. Here's what I tried by accessing terminal from login screen:

1. Checking ownership of .Xauthority and .ICEauthority files. Even removed them. Files are fine. When I deleted them, I still got the login loop but the file were not automatically recreated when I tried to login normally. To recreate them I had to manually issue startx.
2. Checking permissions of /tmp directory and even deleted all its content.
3. Tried to login as a test user by creating a new user. It worked but my user does not work.
4. Using startx when opening a terminal from the login screen works. But the login screen still stuck on a login loop if I log out or reboot.
5. Switched to a different login screen gdm3 -­­­> lightdm by using sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm/gdm3 and issuing sudo init 5 to go back to login screen.
6. Checked content of .xsession-errors and .xsessions-errors.old and got the following error messages (which I am not sure I understand):

.xsession-errors (.xsession-errors.old is exactly the same):

```
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1002/bus: Connection refused
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1002/bus: Connection refused
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1002/bus: Connection refused
dbus-update-activation-environment: error: unable to connect to D-Bus: Failed to connect to socket /run/user/1002/bus: Connection refused
```

I looked at this bus file and did ls -la on it and this is what I got:

```
srw-rw-rw- 1 myusername myusername 0 Apr 11 10:02 /run/user/1002/bus
```

Cause of the error:
I am not sure what happened as I tried to run some calculation task and I think it was hungry for too much ressources on my computer. My computer froze and I had to do a hard reboot by pressing the power button. After that, I got stuck into this loggin loop problem.

Question: Any idea what these error message means? Any idea how to solve this loggin loop issue?

**EDIT:**

- Reinstalling the graphic card drivers didn't solve the problem.
- Trying out "lubuntu-desktop" works though! I can use a regular session on this light environment. ubuntu-desktop does not work (still login loop issue).

Comment: Did you find a fix?

Comment: It fixed itself eventually...

Answer (score 2):

I've run into the same issue and reinstalling lightdm fixed the issue for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm
sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had this happen for one user account on Ubuntu and it was caused by something screwy in the user's `~/.config` directory. To quickly fix, switch to log in as the user via the console (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F3</kbd> or similar) then at the prompt do `mv ~/.config ~/config.old`. Switch back to the GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F1</kbd> or similar) and you should be able to log in. Note that all config settings (background etc.) will be back to defaults.